# T-SQL, арифметические операции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Даны таблицы с начальным количеством единиц на складе, с прогнозом расхода товара за неделю:
`(Stocks: SKU_Name(pk название товара)`, `Volume_tons(начальное  кол-во единиц товара))`,`(Forecast: SKU_NAME(fk название товара)`, `Week_Number (номер недели)`, `Volume_tons (прогноз расхода))`.

Нужно рассчитать на сколько дней должно хватить товара.

Алгоритм вычисления на псевдокоде получается, его реально без применения временных таблиц перевести на синтаксис T-SQL?:

```
if ((stocks.volume_tons - SUM(forecast.volume_tons)) < 0) {
int cover = 7 * ((forecast.week_number - 1) + (stocks.volume_tons - SUM(forecast.volume_tons)-forecast.volume_tons)/forecast.volume_tons)
```

Вот такой вот скрипт получается:

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT, @weekCount INT, @nameSKU varchar(4), @cover float; --объявление счётчика, числа недель, названия SKU, покрытия в днях
SET @intFlag = 0; --счётчик сбрасываем на ноль
SET @weekCount = 5; --число недель берём = 5
SET @nameSKU = 'SKU6'; --задаём SKU

WHILE (@intFlag <= @weekCount) --пока не достигли последней недели
BEGIN
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1; --инкремент счетчика. начинаем сразу с 1 недели

    -- если на конец недели остаётся отрицательное количество SKU
    IF ((select volume_tons from stocks where SKU_Name=@nameSKU) - --объем начального стока для заданного SKU
    (select sum(volume_tons) from forecast where SKU_Name=@nameSKU and Week_number<=@intFlag)) < 0 --сумма всех прогнозируемых продаж до текущей недели включительно
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @lastWeekStock float, @curWeekForecast float; --объявили буферные переменные для хранения временных значений для удобства чтения запроса (Сток к концу прошлой недели и прогноз продаж на текущей)

    --предусматриваем ситуацию, когда начальный сток < прогноза продаж на 1 неделе
    IF (@intFlag < 2)
        SET @lastWeekStock = (select volume_tons from stocks where SKU_Name=@nameSKU); --объем начального стока для заданного SKU
    ELSE
        SET @lastWeekStock = (select volume_tons from stocks where SKU_Name=@nameSKU) - --объем начального стока для заданного SKU
                         (select sum(volume_tons) from forecast where SKU_name=@nameSKU and Week_number<@intFlag); --сумма прогнозируемых продаж до предыдущей недели включительно

    SET @curWeekForecast = (select volume_tons from forecast where SKU_name=@nameSKU and Week_number=@intFlag); --прогноз продаж на текущей неделе

    --предусматриваем ситуацию, когда прогноз продаж = 0, чтобы не делить на ноль и перейти на следующую неделю
    IF (@curWeekForecast = 0) 
        CONTINUE; --7 дней х (кол-во недель до текущей + сток к концу прошлой недели / прогноз продаж на текущей неделе)
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @cover = 7 * (@intFlag - 1 + @lastWeekStock / @curWeekForecast); --7 дней х (кол-во недель до текущей + сток к концу прошлой недели / прогноз продаж на текущей неделе)
        PRINT @cover; --вывод на экран покрытия в днях
        BREAK;
    END;

END;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Можно попробовать в LinqPad'е написать код на Linq2Sql и получить автоматически сгенерированный SQL.